# Start service every X second with the help of thread as database update frequently

Tags: android, sql, multithreading, service, push-notification

My app is connected with **SQL SERVER** database which **updates daily**, so when i start my activity, log-in form pop-up and user logged in . Now as my database update any second , i want to ***run*** a query **every X second so that any change in database is notified and send notification to user**. So , I think thread will come in play so that query run every second . Now, i want to know **how to implement Thread** in this and run **Service for notification** so that whenever data is updated in database user will be notified via push notification.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#scheduleservice_scheduling. use Alaram Manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) along with a Timer as below:

```
public class MyBackgroundService extends IntentService
{
private Timer mBackGroundTimer;
public MyBackgroundService()
    {
        super("myservice");
        this.mBackGroundTimer=new Timer();
    }
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mBackGroundTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
            { 
                public void run() 
                    { 

                        try 
                            {
                                //your db query here
                            } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    } 
            },startTime,repeatTime); 
    } // END onHandleIntent()
private void mStopTimer()
    {
        //Call this whenever you need to stop the service
        mBackGroundTimer.cancel();
    }
}
```

and call this inside your activity as below:

```
Intent mInt_BckGrndSrv =  new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyBackgroundService.class);
        startService(mInt_BckGrndSrv);
```

and don't forget to specify it as a service in your manifest.xml as,

```
<service android:name="com.example.MyBackgroundService" android:enabled="true"></service>
```

P.S. For tutorial on different services, check [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html).

Comment: Yes, you sure can use AlarmManager as well. It has a function `setRepeating` which would do your job. However, I showed you how I am using service to do the same.