# run function every X Minutes / Seconds?

Tags: android, background

I want to run in the background a function every x minutes.
The function need to run always, even if the application not started.

How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Always running Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781350/always-running-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using AlarmManager in Android. There is a good tutorial about [services in Android](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html). Or you can do it as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18518270/2003486).

EDIT: startTime is the delay in time (in milliseconds) when you need to start the service running in the background and repeatTime is the interval of time after which the task you need to perform will be invoked (i.e. as you have mentioned in your question, the function will run after every `repeatTime` milliseconds of delay) until you stop the service.

Comment: What i need to set in startTime,repeatTime?

Comment: @nirbe Please check the EDIT part in my answer.